# Grails spring-security-core remember me functionality

Tags: grails, spring-security, remember-me

I'm using the spring-security-core plugin v. 1.2.6 ([documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/)).
I want to implement the [remember me functionality](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/9%20Authentication.html#9.3%20Remember-Me%20Cookie). Configuration and GSP is done well I think. But what do I have to do now in my LoginController to make it work? I can't find any tutorial or good documentation for it.

Comment: If you look at the controller and GSPs that are generated by the plugin when you run the `s2-quickstart` script you can see how to implement it

Answer (score 3):

Nothing, it's on by default. Just make sure that the checkbox is there and has the name `_spring_security_remember_me`

Comment: Burt, after login should I manually set rememberMe to true or something ? I'm using Spring Security Plugin with Grails 2.3.6 and the value of rememberMeParameter doesn't populate. Can you please suggestion ?

Comment: Also the hasCookie value is empty when I print it.